# Not passing correctly parameters to add in a list with blazor

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-server-side

Im triying to create a list of notes that has a form with Title and description. But everytime I wanna add a new Note on the list Im unable to see them. The only thing I can see is the delete button. Im using synfusion for personal use and I don't believe that will be the problem. The think it is that im creating two components, one of them is the "BlocNote" that it will be displayed on the screen and the form "FormCreateNote" that contains the parameters NewTitle and NewDescription. And finally the Page "listNotes" that will contain the form and the component BlocNote. And of course the Note class that contains Title and Description.

```
Class Note

    public class Nota
    {
     
        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    }
```

BlocNote.razor

```
<div class="m4 p-2 rounded-lg shadow" style="background-color: @colores[new Random().Next(colores.Count)] ">

    <h3 class="text-white font-bold rounded-lg">
        @Titulo
    </h3>
    <br />
    <p class="text-white rounded-lg">
        @Descripcion
    </p>
    <br />

    <SfButton CssClass="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @onclick="@BorrarNota">Eliminar</SfButton>
</div>

his back-code

       public partial class BlocNota
    {
        [Parameter] public Nota Nota { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public string Titulo { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public EventCallback BorrarNota { get; set; }

        private readonly List<string> colores = new() { "#F94144", "#F3722C", "#F8961E", "#F9C74F", "#90BE6D", "#43AA8B", "#577590" };
    }
```

FormCrearNota

```
<div class="mb-4">
                    <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2" for="titulo">
                        Titulo
                    </label>
                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                           bind-value="@Titulo" />

                </div>
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2" for="descripcion">
                        Descripcion
                    </label>
                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                           bind-value="@Descripcion" />

                </div>

                <SfButton CssClass="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" OnClick=CancelarNota>
                    Cancelar
                </SfButton>

                <SfButton CssClass="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" OnClick=CrearNota>
                    Crear
                </SfButton>
            </div>
```

his back-code

```
       public partial class FormCrearNotas
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Falta un campo por rellenar")]
        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Falta un campo por rellenar")]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        public string CancelText { get; set; } = "Cancelar";
        public string OkText { get; set; } = "Crear";

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Falta un mensaje")]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public EventCallback CancelarNota { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public EventCallback CrearNota { get; set; }
    }
```

And ListNotes

```
         <SfButton CssClass="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @onclick="(() => MostrarFormulario = true)">
    Agregar Nota
</SfButton>


<br />
<br />

<BlocNota Titulo="Hola" Descripcion="Esto es un ejemplo" />

<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center 2px">
       @if (!notas.Any())
        {
            <p>No hay notas</p>
             }else
        {
    @foreach (var nota in notas)
    {
        <BlocNota Titulo=@nota.Titulo Descripcion=@nota.Descripcion BorrarNota="@(() => EliminarNota(nota))" />
    }
        }
</div>

       @if (MostrarFormulario)
        {

    <FormCrearNotas CancelarNota="@(() => MostrarFormulario = false)" CrearNota="@(()=>AgregarNota(NuevoTitulo, NuevaDescripcion))" />

}
```

his back-code

```
public partial class ListaNotas
    {
        public List<Nota> notas = new();

        public bool MostrarFormulario { get; set; }

        public string NuevoTitulo { get; set; }

        public string NuevaDescripcion { get; set; }


        public void AgregarNota(string NuevoTitulo, string NuevaDescripcion)
        {
                Nota nota = new Nota { Titulo = NuevoTitulo, Descripcion = NuevaDescripcion };
                notas.Add(nota);
                NuevoTitulo = "";
                NuevaDescripcion = "";
                MostrarFormulario = false;
        }

        public void EliminarNota(Nota nota)
        {
            notas.Remove(nota);

        }
    }
```

idk why I cannot see the Title and Description from every BlocNotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you never pass Titulo and Descripcion strings from FormCrearNotas component back to ListaNotas. The result is that ListaNotas.NuevoTitulo and Listanotas.NuevaDescripcion are always null !!!

Consider to pass them back in a custom callback event or in other way.

In addition:

1. [removed as per T.Trassoudaine comment]
2. You do a wrong binding in FormCrearNotas. Use:

   ```
   <input @bind="Titulo" />
   ```

   or use the InputText blazor component:

   ```
   <InputText @bind-Value="@Titulo" />
   ```

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually, `OnClick` does exist, see the [doc](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/blazor/Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.SfButton.html#Syncfusion_Blazor_Buttons_SfButton_OnClick).

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine, you're right. Sorry but I'm not a Syncfusion user :( so I used the native event. I edit the answer and remove that part.